# Compare count result in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

How to compare count result of 2 select statements in sqlite (version 1.0.103)

```
Select Count(1) from tblData == Count(1) from tblData where Status in ('Done','InProgress')
```

I want to compare these 2 counts and return true if equal, return false otherwise.

Note, I can't use IIF statement as it is not supported in v1.0.103

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN Status IN ('Done','InProgress') THEN 1 END)
FROM tblData;
```

or:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) = SUM(Status IN ('Done','InProgress')) 
FROM tblData;
```

Both queries will return either `1` for `true` or `0` for `false`.